# Toggle Shift Key

Tags: code-golf, keyboard

## Objective

Given an ASCII character, toggle its "shift-ness" on the standard US keyboard (ANSI-INCITS 154-1988 (R1999)), then output it.

## Mapping

```
) ↔️ 0
! ↔️ 1
@ ↔️ 2
# ↔️ 3
$ ↔️ 4
% ↔️ 5
^ ↔️ 6
& ↔️ 7
* ↔️ 8
( ↔️ 9
" ↔️ '
+ ↔️ =
, ↔️ <
- ↔️ _
. ↔️ >
/ ↔️ ?
: ↔️ ;
(Capital Latin letters) ↔️ (Small Latin letters)
[ ↔️ {
\ ↔️ |
] ↔️ }
` ↔️ ~
(ASCII whitespaces and control characters are left intact)
```

## Rule

- Non-ASCII characters fall into *don't care* situation.

## Examples

Given a character `0`, output `)`.
Given a character `C`, output `c`.
Given a character  (space), output .
Given a character `\t` (horizontal tab), output `\t`.
Given a character `\a` (bell), output `\a`.

Comment: Is it ok if we do the UK keyboard? Just four differences that I can tell.

Comment: @ouflak I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## x86-16, Genuine IBM PC, <del>32</del> <del>31</del> 29 bytes

```
00000000: b4f0 8ec0 bfe5 e8b3 3ab1 74a0 8200 f2ae  ........:.t.....
00000010: 3acb 7f02 f7db 268a 41ff cd29 c3         :.....&.A..).
```

Build with `xxd -r`.

**Unassembled listing:**

```
B4 F0       MOV  AH, 0F0H               ; BIOS segment address (F000H)
8E C0       MOV  ES, AX                 ; set ES to BIOS segment for SCASB
BF E8E5     MOV  DI, E8E5H              ; set to LABEL K10 
B3 3A       MOV  BL, 58                 ; size of table 
B1 74       MOV  CL, 58*2               ; size of both tables 
A0 0082     MOV  AL, BYTE PTR DS:[82H]  ; get input char from command line 
F2/ AE      REPNZ SCASB                 ; search BIOS table for char 
3A CB       CMP  CL, BL                 ; found in the lowercase table? 
7F 02       JG   UPPER                  ; if so, convert with uppercase table by adding
F7 DB       NEG  BX                     ; otherwise subtract the offset 
        UPPER: 
26:8A 41 FF MOV  AL, ES:[BX+DI-1]       ; get char from table
CD 29       INT  29H                    ; DOS fast write to console 
C3          RET                         ; return to DOS
```

**Input/Output:**

[image]

**How does it work?**

Well, the PC BIOS already contains all of the code and tables necessary for this since it actually handles the conversion of scan codes received from the keyboard to ASCII chars (in real/DOS mode at least).  There's no way (that I know of) to actually hook this on just *any* "PC-compatible" BIOS, however if you know the location of the table in ROM (on the IBM PC it starts at `F000:E8E5`), you can use that.

On Page A-25 of Appendix A the [IBM PC Technical Reference](https://ibm.retropc.se/manuals/IBM_5150_Technical_Reference_6025005_AUG81.pdf) (listing of the entire source code of the PC BIOS) is the disassembly of this table:

[image]

Unfortunately, this address will be different on any given PC-clone BIOS and of course, there's no guarantee that it would even be implemented in the same way by anyone else.  Thus, this submission is guaranteed to run only on a *Genuine IBM PC*.  Go Big Blue!

Answer (score 9):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>110 ... 97</s>  96 bytes

```javascript
c=>(s=")0@2^6&7*8(9\"'+=-_:;`~")[s.indexOf(c)^1]||(B=Buffer)([([n]=B(c),n%127>32)<<4+n/64^n])+''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BT8JAFITv/IqXJtr3XKm0EEDbJabcPMiBY2m1KV2swbdmFw0E9OgP8Cf6R@rCkctkkm8yM6/lZ2kr07xvuqyXdatkW8kJWulR7z4qhpejqzHeLjxfyO7TXfz87VFmg4aX9XamsKIizA8HTGX6oVRtCDPMOJepI9d8EUajST@iJBkIvhkOCs5J@H6rtEEGCb0YGBIIo7EzQhDsOwCVA/ONaXgVKKPfpi@lmbpjyBQfqWar13Ww1it8mM8eA3uKNmrnFkGAD38/v04FnNHjV3IVX@0/)

#### How?

We use a lookup table for these pairs:

```
) ↔️ 0
@ ↔️ 2
^ ↔️ 6
& ↔️ 7
* ↔️ 8
( ↔️ 9
" ↔️ '
+ ↔️ =
- ↔️ _
: ↔️ ;
` ↔️ ~
```

For all other characters, we use the following code:

```javascript
(B = Buffer)([   // generate a buffer from a singleton array:
  (              //
    [n] = B(c),  //   n = ASCII code of the input character
    n % 127 > 32 //   1 if 32 < n < 127, or 0 otherwise
  )              //
  << 4 + n / 64  //   left-shifted by 4 if n < 64, or by 5 otherwise
  ^ n            //   XOR'ed with n
]) + ''          // end of Buffer(); coerce it to a string
```

which supports these 3 cases:

- If \$32<n<64\$, we XOR the ASCII code with \$16\$, which is what we need for:

  ```
  ! ↔️ 1
  # ↔️ 3
  $ ↔️ 4
  % ↔️ 5
  , ↔️ <
  . ↔️ >
  / ↔️ ?
  ```
- If \$64\le n<127\$, we XOR the ASCII code with \$32\$, which toggles the case of letters and also works for these pairs:

  ```
  [ ↔️ {
  \ ↔️ |
  ] ↔️ }
  ```
- If \$n\le32\$ or \$n=127\$, the character is left unchanged (ASCII code XOR'ed with \$0\$).

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 34 bytes

```
T`-~A-]d';-?/.+,:"(*&^%$#@!)}-_`Ro
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc89TgJRFAXg/qzi8v8GGMB/BRUIFQmV2CkwL8MzTDLOkDcvsUAobW1cjOtxAy5hHItjYfflnuTcHGtclOg8vw/8w9hfrBsDf9jttNr9smrWl7VqZVTy9v4quEvz3JOvt4/vz3fpoUQeYUQeo0KeoEqeokaeYUmeo05eoEleQpFXKJMNtMgbtMlr@OQKHfIWXXKIPjmAmuht5HQsM13sldg4Z2z2N0jNn3X8P8QD4x0eyVcsyD0C8gA1nk@mU3nZRM5kWx2aTHSyljBNnE1jCTfa6vC3VrQ1xYsnJ1HiipP3Aw) Link includes test cases.

Explanation: The `T` command is Retina's transliteration operation. Among its special characters are:

- `` ` ``: Delimit the parts of the command
- `-`: Introduce a range (this suppresses the following special characters so `d-o` just means `defghijklmno`)
- `_`: Delete the matching character
- `d`: `0-9`
- `R`: Reverse the next range
- `o`: Take the source string as the range

The trick is therefore to create as many ranges as possible to reduce the length, plus avoiding having the `-` and `_` characters where they would be interpreted as a special character and avoiding the `` ` `` at all by including it inside a range. Additionally arranging for the range to transliterate to its reversal allows that to be expressed very cheaply.

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + core utilities, <sup><s>58</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>51</s></sup> 49 bytes

Added <s>47</s> 50 bytes to fix a bug kindly pointed out by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe).
Saved 8 bytes thanks to [Value Ink](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52194/value-ink)!!!
Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Mitchell Spector](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59825/mitchell-spector)!!!

```bash
a='"A-]`=<_>?)!@#$%^&*(;'
b=\'a-~+-:
tr $a$b $b$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYvLDoIwFET3/YoRq4AG4lZLQf/jKhaB8EiKAVby@PWKMbqZTM6ZSVRXmN5xB6OkbV28610GcRi5q/Oab27bnSNslkiylTfvvRPrW3DFE/CEKzOxvGlRotQYDr5/nEA2SIICUAwKQRFIYFC@/1rcABpBS5kF0oZVkjvZo2jAS4zoXVH/QfUFz7bUfQ5r08EL8UvS1ueyjHgtWNrozLwB)

Comment: I like the idea behind this, but it doesn't seem to be coming out right.  For example, 'A' => 'b'.  Also, it's not actually bash -- it's "bash + core utilities", so I think the language listed should be changed accordingly.  (tr isn't a bash built-in.)

Comment: @MitchellSpector Sorry it's a bit of a hack, did this from my phone! T_T Will fix it when I get a chance.

Comment: From your phone? That's impressive in itself! I don't think I could do that.

Comment: @MitchellSpector Have termux which is very sweet! :-)

Comment: I haven't seen that app, but it must be nice :) .  @Noodle9

Comment: Do you really need the square brackets around each quote? The Wikipedia article on tr syntax doesn't seem to indicate the need for either unless you're using a special sequence like `[:alnum:]`. I think removing them won't affect the program, but I can't be sure until you fix the other issues that were brought up. Also, I feel like you don't need to escape the `!`

Comment: @ValueInk I made the whole string a regex for the `[0-9]`, `[A-Z]` and `[a-z]` regex's.

Comment: Yes, but the [tr page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix)) says you don't need it. Might depend on the version of coreutils you have but the one on TIO works this way. [Example with reduced charset](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifmpyRr2CsUKMQ87@kSEHJQNdSSUFJU9FBWUU1Tk1LQ@n/fwA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: @ValueInk Sweet! Just got back from holiday after a long journey. Will sort this out properly on my much missed box tomorrow - thanks! :-)

Comment: @ValueInk Fixed! Nice one - using your no `[]` tip and it works, thanks! :-)

Comment: @MitchellSpector All fixed now.

Comment: @Giuseppe All fixed now.

Comment: Nice solution! -

Comment: I think you can shave off 2 bytes by removing the single quotes around '0-9'.

Comment: @MitchellSpector Yes indeed, nice one - thanks! :-)

Comment: By the way, I've just added an answer which is basically a port of this nice solution to pure bash (without using tr or other utilities).  It's shorter than my earlier pure bash solution, which uses a different approach.  (I tried to tag you in the answer, but apparently you can't do that.)

Comment: Apparently you can’t tag people in answers, only in comments, and even then it seems you can only tag people who commented earlier. (This is unless I’m missing something, of course!)

Comment: @MitchellSpector I see what you mean now, you can mention them but they don't get notified. Looks like a wrinkle in the software! If only the had access to people who ciuld fix this... T_T

Comment: Exactly. But I think it’s on purpose, to prevent spamming people who haven’t expressed an interest in the answer.

Comment: @MitchellSpector Always the bad ones who spoil things, makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 86 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

This solution [has been out-golfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199947/43319) but is preserved due to being interesting for its sourcing of the data.

Anonymous prefix lambda. Requires 0-based indexing (`⎕IO←0`).

```apl
{⍵∊a←↑'[!-~]{2}'⎕S'&'↓⍉↑'\w\w...'⎕R(5⍴'')↓11 71↑30↓⎕FMT⌂notes.keyboards:a⌷⍨~@1⊃⍸⍵=a⋄⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/6sf9W591NGVCOQ8apuoHq2oWxdbbVSrDlQRrK6m/qht8qPeTpBMTHlMuZ6eHkgiSMP0Ue8WdXVNoKyhoYK5IVDe2ACktG@qm2/Io56mvPyS1GK97NTKpPzEopRiq8RHPdsf9a6oczB81NX8qHcH0FLbxEfdLUC69n8ayO7ePrDMGqDBh9YbAw0EOSDIGUiGeHgG/09TUDdQ5wKSzmBSAUxygkl2dQA)

This works by extracting the character pairs from [a built-in note about keyboards](https://dfns.dyalog.com/n_keyboards.htm).

`{`…`}` "dfn"; argument character is `⍵`:

`⌂notes.keyboards` the built-in string

`⎕FMT` ForMaT as a character matrix

`30↓` drop the first 30 lines

`11 71↑` take the first 11 lines' first 71 columns

`↓` split into list of strings

`'\w\w...'⎕R(`…`)` PCRE **R**eplace word-character,word-character,any-symbol,any-symbol with:

`''` the empty string

`5⍴` reshaped to length 5, padding with spaces; i.e. 5 spaces

`↑` mix list of strings into character matrix

`⍉` transpose

`↓` split matrix into list of strings

`'[!-~]{2}'⎕R'&'` PCRE **S**earch and return any pair of printable ASCII characters

`↑` mix list of character pairs into two-column matrix

`a←` store in `a` (for ***a***ll)

`⍵∊`…`:` if the argument character is a member of that matrix:

`⍵=` Boolean matrix mask where they are equal

`⍸` get indices where true

`⊃` pick the first (row,column) pair

`~@1` negate the number at position 1 (the column; i.e. 1→0 and 0→1)

`a⌷⍨` use that to index into the matrix of **a**ll pairs

`⋄` else:

`⍵` the argument character

Comment: Is taking the first 71 columns necessary?

Comment: Could `'\w\w...'⎕R(5⍴'')` be replaced by a reverse-each line (so that the Caps<>Lock mapping is never used)?

Comment: @JonathanAllan The 71 chops "Backspace" into  "Backs" and reversing would expose "Enter" instead.

Comment: Ah, I see, so you'd need to ignore all characters paired with spaces too.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>99</s> 95 bytes

Same strategy as @Arnauld's answer.

*-4 bytes thanks to @mypetlion*

```python
lambda c,s=")0!1@2#3$4%5^6&7*8(9\"'+=,<-_.>/?:;[{\\|]}`~":[c.swapcase(),s[s.find(c)^1]][c in s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc1JDoIwGEDhvaf4xalVRAEHRFHv0RathUoTLaQlMcbh6oi7t/nyqmddlDpsJCRAmxu/XzIOwrWJg@dd/xj0wv5isExXw/U4QhvqjCaJu5uevP3sEG/Ji9I3@5y/TkyEZx@8EtzmCLuWWE8qnSGBU58xIkBpsKyRpQH1b8P1NUd@EOG4A6J9i8IghTtQGaVrJFuImx8)

### Explanation

- `` s=")0!1@2#3$4%5^6&7*8(9\"'+=,<-_.>/?:;[{\\|]}`~" `` contains all pairs of special toggles.
- `s[s.index(c)^1]` gets the index of the other character from the same pair
- If the character is a Latin or control character (`c in s` is `False`), `c.swapcase()` is returned. `c.swapcase()` toggles the case of a Latin character, but doesn't affect control character.

Comment: Change everything after the colon to `[c.swapcase(),s[s.find(c)^1]][c in s]` to save 4 bytes.

Comment: Clever use of boolean index!

Comment: Thanks @mypetlion for spotting the erroneous extra space at the end!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>38</s>  37 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“Æz⁶ɦG!€u<ʂCP]ƭƝ’œ?ØṖḟØB¤ḊØD;ṙ21,ƊyŒs
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters which yields a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AYQAe/9qZWxsef//4oCcw4Z64oG2yaZHIeKCrHU8yoJDUF3Grcad4oCZxZM/w5jhuZbhuJ/DmELCpOG4isOYRDvhuZkyMSzGinnFknP///8HQmVsbAlUYWIgU3BhY2UpIUAjJCVeJiooIissLS4vOltcXWAwMTIzNDU2Nzg5Jz08Xz4/O3t8fX4)**

#### How?

Forms a mapping for non alphabetic characters, applies the translate atom,  `y`,
and then swaps case.

```
“Æz⁶ɦG!€u<ʂCP]ƭƝ’œ?ØṖḟØB¤ḊØD;ṙ21,ƊyŒs - Link: list of characters, S
“Æz⁶ɦG!€u<ʂCP]ƭƝ’                     - base 250 number              =53994992086540427749431907521542401
                        ¤             - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
                   ØṖ                 -   printable characters       = !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
                      ØB              -   base-62 characters         =0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
                     ḟ                -   filter discard             = !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
                 œ?                   - lexicographical permutation  = '=<_>?;{|}~)!@#$%^&*("+,-./:[\]`
                         Ḋ            - dequeue                      ='=<_>?;{|}~)!@#$%^&*("+,-./:[\]`
                          ØD          - digit characters             =0123456789
                            ;         - concatenate                  =0123456789'=<_>?;{|}~)!@#$%^&*("+,-./:[\]`
                                 Ɗ    - last three links as a monad:
                              21      -   twenty-one
                             ṙ        -   rotate left                =)!@#$%^&*("+,-./:[\]`0123456789'=<_>?;{|}~
                                ,     -   pair                       =)!@#$%^&*("+,-./:[\]`0123456789'=<_>?;{|}~ and 0123456789'=<_>?;{|}~)!@#$%^&*("+,-./:[\]`
                                  y   - translate (S)
                                   Œs - swap case
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>92</s> 91 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @ValueInk*

```perl
s/[]a-z{}|\\[]/$&^$"/gei;y/0-9)!@#$%^&*(`~\-=_+';":,.\/<>?/)!@#$%^&*(0-9~`_+\-=":';<>?,.\//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YPzo2UbequrYmJiY6Vl9FLU5FST89NdO6Ut9A11JT0UFZRTVOTUsjoS5G1zZeW91ayUpHL0bfxs5eHyEJVFmXEK8NVKFkpW4NlAMp0f//PzEpOSIyytDI2MTUzNzC0gChIzo2pqa2@l9@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQ4P/ugUA)

Comment: `/[]a-z{}|\\[]/` lets you cut out the extra backslash while still matching `]` in your first regex. Also, why did you put those particular characters into its own `s///` operation instead of wrapping them into the `y///`? I don't know much about Perl but I did use the Ruby `y///` analogue (`tr`) in my own solution without needing to do a regex sub at all. Maybe that could help you out with golfing your solution.

Comment: You don't *need* the substitution, but it works out to be a couple of bytes shorter than accounting for those characters in the translation.

Comment: Hmmm. Could you have 2 strings (one with upper only and one with lower only) and pass them into `tr` in different orders similar to what I did in my Ruby solution? I'm not sure how costly it is to declare variables in Perl though

Comment: No.  `tr///` is a quote-like operator in Perl.  It does not do variable interpolation.  You'd have to put it inside an `eval`, costing even more bytes.

Comment: I figured it out; `eval` might cost bytes, but not as much as it saves. [77 bytes, probably can be golfed further depending on how the strings are set up](https://tio.run/##JcvbDsFAEADQbzHG3XS3KGrV5QO8006xK32QNNogEtr6dCvivJ88uaaetagDIE0vSX4QUaxafYdZHEGhCeCwprBTW9UZG/tmt90rymrGMF8s36CSh07hKVCjEWiYUQuwVpvTdhe6g@HIG0@mvvztf45iLqvik@X3c3a5Wdp4jnSlpfwL "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>53</s> <s>36</s> 35 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.šžQžiмDœ•1ĀêŽƵÆ{çIΣeÿí‚Ð"pkālrÙ•è‡
```

-1 byte implicitly thanks to *@Grimmy* due to his comment.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AUcAuP9vc2FiaWX//y7FocW@UcW@adC8U0TigKIxxIDDqsW9xrXDhnvDp0nOo2XDv8Ot4oCaw5AicGvEgWxyw5nigKIuSeKAof//Xg) or [verify all printable ASCII characters](https://tio.run/##AVYAqf9vc2FiaWX/xb5Rdnk/IiDihpIgIj95/y7FocW@UcW@adC8U0TigKIxxIDDqsW9xrXDhnvDp0nOo2XDv8Ot4oCaw5AicGvEgWxyw5nigKIuSeKAof8s/w). NOTE: The TIO versions use the `S•...•.I` (builtin for the n'th permutation of a list) instead of `œ•...•è` (push all permutations of the string (extremely slow bottleneck for a string this large), and index into it).

**Explanation:**

```python
.š        # Switch-case of the (implicit) input-character (if it's a letter)
  žQ      # Push all printable ASCII characters:
          #   !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
    žiм   # Remove all letters [A-Za-z]:
          #   !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
  D       # Duplicate it
   œ      # Push a list of all permutations of this string
    •1ĀêŽƵÆ{çIΣeÿí‚Ð"pkālrÙ•
         "# Push compressed integer 540470878544692028277787799913384202055137480696656
     è    # Index it into the string-list of permutations:
          #   1'3457"908=<_>?)!@#$%^&*(;:,+./2{|}6-~[\]`
  ‡       # Transliterate the characters at the same indices
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•1ĀêŽƵÆ{çIΣeÿí‚Ð"pkālrÙ•` is `540470878544692028277787799913384202055137480696656`.

This number(+1) is generated by [the Jelly builtin `Œ¿`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opEP7////r2Cobmxiaq5kaWBhaxNvZ6@p6KCsohqnpqVhbaWjradvVF1Ta6ZbFx0Tm/BfQVEJKKemrqGppa2jq6dvYGgE1GtmbmFpZW1ja2fvAFQVF58A1FEHAA), which gets the 1-based index of the permutation.

Comment: Oooh we have an nth-permutation built-in, why did i never notice that! Though I guess it doesn't actually save any bytes over `œ` + `è`...

Comment: @Grimmy Hmm, seeing your comment actually made me realize that `œ...è` is a byte shorter here, since `.I` doesn't work on strings (only on lists). So I can drop the `S`.

Answer (score 2):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>170</s> 165 bytes

```bash
a=`echo {A..Z}`')!@#$%^&*("+,-./:[\]`'
b=`echo {a..z}`0123456789"'=<_>?;{|}~"
c=$a$b
d=$b$a
for((;n<164;n++)){ [ "$1" = "${c:n:1}" ]&&echo ${d:n:1}&&exit;}
echo "$1"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzdDsEwAEbv@xRVtR@jlBnWFXsNM9puZG62BBei6tVrlrj6ck5OPiXvlbWSi3NRNVCnhOyNcP3ero8HR2fooWA0JpM4O@TCBeqfSUJeRkzpbB4uouVqjVyenDZbpt/mg0DBscQKlBwrLMGluXkeqxMahawOAt/XMIMIUwR5O7qI65gaBHPH6b6xLjvT4vP6YAZ09tdba9Mv)

I decided to implement a solution inspired by @Noodle9's very nice answer, but using pure bash without any utilities (like tr).

Note that you need to run this in an empty directory; this can be fixed at the cost of 2 bytes by using quotes for `"{d:n:1}"`.  (This issue only arises with a non-empty current directory when the input is `8`, so the output is supposed to be `*`.)

On the other hand, you can gain 2 bytes if you don't require output for the input `\n`: just eliminate the quotes in the final `echo`.

Comment: You save 3 bytes using `echo {a..z} {0..9}` [like this](https://tio.run/##PYvBEsEwGITveYpVIS0SrhUpXoOfSqlRZlpTPUnr1avGcNnZ@b7dxD4ubeUHrrVGeEFv1eeD/XDkjydSTedrudkS7Q6CJYaEmMnQLOJoqa18urp5CVaV4JYn4Am3bcPORYkMWQ43UypsQAJkQAtQDIpAS5CGs0o9O@dANagrL41Twa6G@@nxUoBnqFEF@vYH1y@4l1leneENHpARfkm597l0I37T7FTkafsG).

Comment: @Noodle9 Thanks for the suggestion.  I had tried that before posting, but it was a little bit longer that way.   (The problem is that `{0..9}` expands to `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`, so I needed to add spaces into the other string to make the two strings still match up correctly.)  But maybe you figured out some clever way of dealing with that?  (Your link looks like it's just a link to your original answer, not to whatever you intended to link to.)

Comment: Sorry I sent the wrong link. I didn't perform any magic, simply substituted `{0-9}` for `0123456789` and it worked for your test. So incorrect then. :-(

Comment: @Noodle9  That's a shame -- I was hoping you had come up with some cool trick for getting past that issue!  (If it worked for you on some test, you must have gotten lucky with the particular input you happened to try.)

Comment: @Noodle9 Unfortunately, that doesn't work :( .  If you look at the test in your link, you'll see that, for instance, `b` gets mapped to `b`, instead of to `B`.  I investigated it a bit when I was working on this answer, and it turns out that the `{A..Z}` construct isn't expanded on the right side of an assignment statement.

Comment: Yes,  just noticed letters aren't working.

Comment: [166](https://tio.run/##NY7dUsIwFITv8xRrDG1jJVJFlIYUfQ0J0j8YCjOpA71wDOHVSwG52dk955udzbP9um0CbttMpctiXcN@CvHlUp/ffdyz3rf3ENDwsS@e4pmepz7Jb1gmxJ9LB9Hzy/B19PY@pr6aLJKptAd3pKRQLGM5KRXLWUZW9S4IpJlEo6E0Yci5LGvMwCIoUGaL2MSRo5h73qWb2fJy6eJv1XSsWZLrI2rduQwVKgM7EGLsoH1oBT2BXkAn0FNo@T8P2kIfoDtzlChrslEsaMAqLrdXt@HyZ1eZZgXa26Of4Kba0I7rALCtJOcJbXsC) 3rd time lucky! :D

Comment: @Noodle9  That was actually what I mentioned in the last paragraph of the answer -- "On the other hand, you can gain 2 bytes if you don't require output for the input `\n`: just eliminate the quotes in the final `echo`."  You can do this, but then it doesn't have the right output for input `\n`.  Normally the output is the intended output character followed by a `\n`, but if you do this, then the output for `\n` is just `\n`, instead of `\n\n`.  I felt that was at best borderline acceptable, so I didn't do it.

Comment: @Noodle9  But thanks for looking at it!

Comment: @Noodle9  I just noticed that you also changed `"$1"` to `$1` in the for loop.  But unfortunately that won't work if the input is a space, for instance.

Comment: Ah, this reminds me of writing scripts that'll process every weird filename possible! :-)

Comment: I know -- avoiding weird characters is a real nuisance with bash.  But that's really only because it's so flexible, so I can't complain.

Comment: True, bash is amazingly powerful working on the command line where everything is a stream of characters that process streams of characters. Love it! :-)

Comment: I agree :).  @Noodle9

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 87 bytes

```julia
x->Char[0:32;b"1'3457\"908=<_>?)!@#$%^&*(;:,+./2";97:125;b"6-~";65:93;96;127][Int(x)+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7LboJAAEX39yuu44PB94CAMII2XfUXimhpKimNoQamqenDX6fWszirk5v79nEsc3Vui7g9T5L717xO55Hr6GehLHfhBVsRzpfxap@s7c6m2@vvBkOpo/FoOnOEDoNIOd619ScXoX0vCl0d@lo5QZY@VEae7ZHKWnNoTMOYdf4phIDNOTpU2NBBly56XKBPDzv6GDDAkEtIhhC0MGKMMVeYcI8pE8y4RkSNlN/Y8gcZf/HEC3Le4YuP//Mo3msalhXToqwbM5XN6VgaeXth25oWrau21c3KysArp7qszLGShnHCQhrbxqF6QfsH)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 60 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
-(,⊃⍨⍳-¯1*⍳)⍨('"''+=,<-_.>/?:;[{\|]}`~',∊')!@#$%^&*(',¨⎕D),-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X1dD51FX86PeFY96N@seWm@oBaQ1gVwNdSV1dW1bHRvdeD07fXsr6@jqmJrY2oQ6dZ1HHV3qmooOyiqqcWpaGuo6h1Y86pvqoqmj@z/tUduER719YAPXPOrdcmi98aO2iUDZ4CBnIBni4Rn8P01B3UCdC0g6g0kFMMkJJtnVAQ)

`-` swap case

`(`…`),` prepend the following:

`⎕D` the digits

`')!@#$%^&*(',¨` prepend each of these characters to the corresponding digit

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten)

`` '"''+=,<-_.>/?:;[{\|]}`~', `` prepend these characters (`''` is an escaped single quote)

`-(`…`)⍨` apply the following function with that as *left* argument and the case-swapped original argument as *right* argument:

`⍳` **ɩ**ndex of the case-swapped argument in the substitution string

`¯1*` negative one raised to that power

`⍳-` subtract that from the **ɩ**ndex of the case-swapped argument in the substitution string

`,⊃⍨` use that to pick an element from the case-swapped argument appended to the substitution string

Answer (score 1):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 217 bytes

```bash
P=printf\ 
a=`$P%x "'$1"`
case $a in 3[ab])x=1;;2[27])x=5;;2[68]|3[79])x=17;;2a|38)x=18;;2b|3d)x=22;;29|30)x=25;;36|5e)x=104;;2d|32|40|5f)x=114;;20|7f)x=0;;60|7e)x=30;;[23]?)x=16;;[4-7]?)x=32
esac
$P\\`$P%o $[0x$a^x]`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc7PCoMwDAbwu09RRsfYYVAbtUqRsTfwXjus/5gXN@YOHvLuXeLtly9fIH3YXjE29ee7rL@5FUmoO9mcd3G6yPTUJUPYJiGDWFYBLvT@uteptdppw8yZRekRnKmOnaEkIJTsktwjjGStyRWCYtMVFJhP3FEZLUYEjZnCfOYo5Uih4UFZWxC5CmSnwd@5U5CzmzkG0Mm0hSGRTdvy728hndpleO6@izE@/g)

Just bash -- no Unix utilities.

Input character is passed as an argument, and the output is on stdout.

**_____________________________________________________________**

**Test runs:**

```bash
$ cat shifttoggle
P=printf\ 
a=`$P%x "'$1"`
case $a in 3[ab])x=1;;2[27])x=5;;2[68]|3[79])x=17;;2a|38)x=18;;2b|3d)x=22;;29|30)x=25;;36|5e)x=104;;2d|32|40|5f)x=114;;20|7f)x=0;;60|7e)x=30;;[23]?)x=16;;[4-7]?)x=32
esac
$P\\`$P%o $[0x$a^x]`


$cat shifttoggleTest
#!/bin/bash

count=1

for s in ')!@#$%^&*("+,-./:' "0123456789'=<_>?;" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '[\]`' '{|}~' $' \a\n\r\t\x7F\x80\x88\x8F'
  do
    echo "TEST #$count"

    for ((n=0;n<${#s};n++))
      do
        c="${s:$n:1}"
        d=`./shifttoggle "$c"`

    # Backticks remove any trailing newline, so restore that here for the case where c is \n (you can check that shifttoggle really prints \n in that case).
    if test -z "$d"
          then
            d=$'\n'
        fi

    if test "$count" -eq 7
          then
            printf "  ASCII %d => ASCII %d\n" "'$c" "'$d"
      else
            echo "  $c => $d"
        fi

      done

      (( count++ ))
      echo ''
  done


$ ./shifttoggleTest 
TEST #1
  ) => 0
  ! => 1
  @ => 2
  # => 3
  $ => 4
  % => 5
  ^ => 6
  & => 7
  * => 8
  ( => 9
  " => '
  + => =
  , => <
  - => _
  . => >
  / => ?
  : => ;

TEST #2
  0 => )
  1 => !
  2 => @
  3 => #
  4 => $
  5 => %
  6 => ^
  7 => &
  8 => *
  9 => (
  ' => "
  = => +
  < => ,
  _ => -
  > => .
  ? => /
  ; => :

TEST #3
  A => a
  B => b
  C => c
  D => d
  E => e
  F => f
  G => g
  H => h
  I => i
  J => j
  K => k
  L => l
  M => m
  N => n
  O => o
  P => p
  Q => q
  R => r
  S => s
  T => t
  U => u
  V => v
  W => w
  X => x
  Y => y
  Z => z

TEST #4
  a => A
  b => B
  c => C
  d => D
  e => E
  f => F
  g => G
  h => H
  i => I
  j => J
  k => K
  l => L
  m => M
  n => N
  o => O
  p => P
  q => Q
  r => R
  s => S
  t => T
  u => U
  v => V
  w => W
  x => X
  y => Y
  z => Z

TEST #5
  [ => {
  \ => |
  ] => }
  ` => ~

TEST #6
  { => [
  | => \
  } => ]
  ~ => `

TEST #7
  ASCII 32 => ASCII 32
  ASCII 7 => ASCII 7
  ASCII 10 => ASCII 10
  ASCII 13 => ASCII 13
  ASCII 9 => ASCII 9
  ASCII 127 => ASCII 127
  ASCII 128 => ASCII 128
  ASCII 136 => ASCII 136
  ASCII 143 => ASCII 143
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 100 bytes

```c
char*strchrnul(),*s=")0@2^6&7*8(9\"'+=-_:;`~\0";f(c){c=s[strchrnul(s,c)-s^1]?:(c%127>32)<<4+c/64^c;}
```

Similar to the Javascript strategy. I'd like to get rid of the extra parentheses but this is pretty good.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY/NDoIwEITvPEXTRG35iYAEkIL6HiJKVhESLaYFLwRfHQvReHZOk9l8u7NgXQGGAcpc6LIRUAre3gg1dZlgau/czJ8HekjWKV4YiXWM2OmV2pgVBGgHidz/GGkCtWTmHLYRgZnjBpuVS@PYM2Dpexmwfqh4g@55xcmzrs5U6zSkNIbAtMkXtSCAEmQzBChGjhsqYxh0Go56tM3YVB3/ECqQBKcc039XjB98IXFpWsEVo/XDGw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, 66 bytes

Builds the "lowercase" and "uppercase" strings so that everything lines up, and connects them together to be passed into the `tr` function so it can do the proper conversions.

```
l="\\-a-z0-9=[-];',./`"
u='_A-Z)!@#$%^&*(+{|}:"<>?~'
$_.tr!u+l,l+u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P8dWKSZGN1G3ykDX0jZaN9ZaXUdPP0GJq9RWPd5RN0pT0UFZRTVOTUtDu7qm1krJxs6@Tp1LJV6vpEixVDtHJ0e79P//BEMjYxNTM3MLSwNdW67C8tSiksrSzPyC6NgYrsTilLT0jKzsHGt1rqqK5LKkvFygBVxcdXCDNeO1uQLDXYNCIkM9/QOqa2u4HINd3Nw9vLx9rJS4oiKcw5z8fIH2cnF5pObk5OsolOcX5aQo/ssvKMnMzyv@r1sAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 189 bytes

```powershell
param($x)if(($s=")0@2^6&7*8(9""'+=-_:;``~").contains($x)){$s[$s.indexof($x)-bxor1]}else{
$n=[byte][char]$x;if($n-in32..64){[char]($n-bxor16)}elseif($n-in65..127){[char]($n-bxor32)}else{$x}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3RCoIwAEXf@4wxaiscqTUrEfqJnsRy2sSBbbIJLcR@faXSS6/nnsNt1ZNrU/Omca5lmj0QtFhUCEGTALw9B1e6jNYHdARgtUm82ynO8zfApFSyY0KaUcc9NCk0RMg7t6oakVdYpf1s4I3h/QLKJC1eHc/SsmY6gzb@PkDpCRkGhNAd7udhZFNI8VT@LLonxA@ify0MZq2Hdhicc5cP)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 111 bytes

```powershell
$k=')!@#$%^&*("+,-./:[\]`'+'A'..'Z'+"0123456789'=<_>?;{|}~"+'a'..'z'
"$k$k$args"[($p=$k|% i*f @args)+72*!!++$p]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDbUsIwEIbv8xRLCGxLCiIe8FSswwPIDHeWCjWmUkFa0zI6Qn31mrSMbGaSf3f//TJJmnxJlS3lel2yCFzYlWzlot3wmqz13O5YlDvd3smNPwsWyPEBez18Qk77p4Oz84vL4dU1unfz0f3tbl/8Uo6hMfwgoWylV6jeMupbLHXZat@CuBOBZ2o2Hw46jQbnLA3KghDPIsSxsI8O2mgbaWvZr@UYHUBRazAaKk0XOXXMZhJfLEMVDJ3DaQM0Ic4hzkAkSkmRA85ChChRMPl/cAVRBqJoTdyYZKMTYsMeWrAjoIMZqANMfqeaJF/1L7F53VEy265zXWjrz6t8Vd2fTMfbLE8@Hl/e9Ujg1SAT060QMssM4zDcFfLzCD8al3F0uKw2Vp2CFOUf)

`i*f` is shortcut for `indexOf`.

Explain:

- The shift series contains 72 chars `)!@#..A B C.. Y Z`.
- The shift-ness series contains 72 chars also
- `$k` contains concatenated shift and shift-ness series
- if `$args` does not found in `$k`, then `indexOf` returns `-1` and script returns the last char from string `$k+$k+$args`. It is `$args`.
- if `$args` found in `$k`, then the script return shifted char.